# Set setReadTimeout and setConnectTimeout after connect

Tags: android, urlconnection, connection-timeout

This is a simple code:

```
URLConnection connection;
URL source = new URL("Some Url");
connection = source.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
connection.connect();
connection.setConnectTimeout(500);
connection.setReadTimeout(500);
```

My question is that if I reset the connection timeout and read timeout of UrlConnection after connect using respective functions, as in above code, will the new values will work or the connection will timeout according to old values? In above, when will timeout happen, after 2000 ms or 500 ms?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Java 7, according to the docs from oracle ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html))

After calling connect on `URLConnection` object, it is an error to try to set those options (connect time out and read time out). So the answer would be it might make your apps make a wrong turn or the set time method will be passed - Depends on what kind of `try/catch` you're using to wrap the code that create `URLConnection`.

Since in android studio when you're creating a new `URLConnection` or when you call `source.openConnection()` to open the connection it will require you to surround it with `try/catch`.

Hope this help :D

Comment: Is there any way to disconnect or stop urlConnection after connect has been called?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, as far as I know you can't close the connection with `URLConnection` but you can do it with `HttpURLConnection` by casting it to`HttpURLConnection`:
`HttpURLConnection conn = null;  URL url = new URL("http://example.com");    conn 
 = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); conn.disconnect();`